# Clojure: Implementing the some function

Tags: clojure, break, tail-recursion

I'm new to clojure and  tried to implement the [some](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some) function (for some specific tests):

```
(my-some even? [1 2 3 4]) => true

(my-some #{3 4} [1 2 3 4]) => 3

(my-some zero? [1 2 3 4]) => nil
```

That's what I came up with so far:

```
(defn my-some [f x]
 (loop [[y & t] x]
  (if (empty? t) nil
   (if (f y)
    (f y)
   (recur t)))))
```

I could imagine there are more idiomatic approaches.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @amalloy Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Noted. In that context this seems reasonably on-topic for SO, and I'm retracting my close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have a bug: `[[y & t] x]` destructures `x`, but the following `empty?` check on `t` means you are ignoring the last element in the sequence. You can see this with

```
(my-some even? [2])
=> nil
```

You can replace `(if (empty? x) nil (else-form))` with `when` and `seq`:

```
(when (seq x) ...)
```

you can then use `first` and `next` to deconstruct the sequence:

```
(defn my-some [f x]
  (when (seq x)
    (if (f (first x))
      (f (first x))
      (recur f (rest x)))))
```

the call to `recur` is then back into `my-some` so you need to pass the predicate `f`.

you can replace `(if x x (else ....))` with `(or x (else ...))`:

```
(defn my-some [f x]
  (when (seq x)
    (or (f (first x)) (recur f (next x)))))
```

you can compare this with the [`implementation of some`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/33712e9a56abc628f12ff12b07097cbd9422c499/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2692)

Comment: Good points. Thanks for clarifying.
Didn't know about next-fn. That's what I was looking for all the time.
My solution was actually just meant to be working for the test cases.
Anyway I prefer your general solution.